# Distance matrix to coordinates points

Tags: python, r, math, geometry, distance

Given a set of n (n > 4) points and its distances and knowing that the Menger determinant is equal to zero, how can I obtain the coordinates in R^3 of these points?

Similar questions in:

[1] [Using distance matrix to find coordinate points of set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096783/using-distance-matrix-to-find-coordinate-points-of-set-of-points)

[2] [Finding the coordinates of points from distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963054/finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix)

I've used [1] as my main reference however I do not know how to handle this algorithm in a 3D plot.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? The basic idea is to add one point at a time that satisfies the distance constraints for (up to four) previous points.

Comment: Perhaps posting this to math.stackoverflow would yield better results