# Coordinates of points from distance matrix - implementation problem

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Problem: Following code does not provide given example coordinates as it is expected. (what algoirthm? - Please refer to link below)

I tried to implement algorithm described here: [finding the coordinates of points from distance matrix@math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix)

Code:

```
# https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix

import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

example = np.array([[0,0],[1,3],[4,4]])
distance_matrix = spatial.distance_matrix(example,example)
 
def get_m_matrix(distance_matrix):
    d = distance_matrix
    shape = d.shape
    out = np.zeros(shape)
    for i in range(shape[0]):
        for j in range(shape[1]):
            out[i,j] = ( d[0,j]**2 + d[i,0]**2 - d[i,j]**2)/2
    return out
 
m_matrix = get_m_matrix(distance_matrix)
eigenvalue, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(m_matrix)
eigenvalue_matrix = np.diag(eigenvalue)
assert np.equal(np.round(np.dot(np.dot(eigenvectors, eigenvalue_matrix),np.linalg.inv(eigenvectors))),np.round(m_matrix)).all()
X = np.dot(eigenvectors, eigenvalue_matrix**0.5)
 
print('example',example,sep='\n')
print('distance_matrix',distance_matrix,sep='\n')
print('m_matrix',m_matrix,sep='\n')
print('eigenvalue',eigenvalue,sep='\n')
print('eigenvectors',eigenvectors,sep='\n')
print('eigenvalue_matrix',eigenvalue_matrix,sep='\n')
print('result',X,sep='\n')
```

And I think I don't get something in its description. I read and watched some videos on eigenvalue decomposition. Check numpy docs on funcitions used there. I am pretty sure M matrix is fine (found some other question, but algo was a bit different, nevertheless M matrix equation was the same). Another thing, I checked `np.linalg.eig` on example from youtube and eigenvectors did not matched. Assertion worked but It still puzzles me.

One more thing, if you use equations in answers, **PLEASE DESCRIBE VARIABLES**. You are not talking to an expert, and no expert will read you 'cause they know. Answer like to a child. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question here? The code provided works without error. What output did you expect when compared to the output you get?

Comment: Grismar, thanks but this code is my own. If you would click a link provided you would get that I expect to get the same coordinates as given in example variable.
Also edited question.
btw. This should output coordinates as provided in example variable.

Comment: You cannot recover the orientation of a collection of points from distances alone (as mentioned in one of the solutions).  My guess is that the solution is "correct", but is rotated relative to your initial `example` points.  You can confirm by inspection that `X` has the same distances to the origin as the original points: `np.sum(example**2, axis=1)` <-> `np.sum(X**2, axis=1)`

Comment: Good point, but thought about it. The result from above is [[0,0], [2.96, 1.11], [5.62, -0.58]], two first look ok, but third one is off, and I can't see any simple rotation to make it right. I added more points, but results were even more nonsense.
On other thread I read that there are some other limitations to this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096783/using-distance-matrix-to-find-coordinate-points-of-set-of-points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096783/using-distance-matrix-to-find-coordinate-points-of-set-of-points) but these should not apply to this example I guess.

Comment: It looks correct to me.  The recovered distances for both `X` and `example` points are: 3.16, 5.65, 3.16.  A set of points actually has *two* gauge freedoms (distances are preserved under rotation and translation)

Comment: If you really want to find the linear transformation mapping between the point sets, you could start by finding the translation between their respective centroids.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. I haven't check it that far, but indeed distance matrix is the same, thou I don't really understand what you wrote ;) (no need to explain, that's homework ;)). Actually this is good enough for my needs, but would you be able to suggest a solution, i.e. to apply proper rotation to obtain input coordinates as an answer?