# Distance Array to XY Coordinates in Python

Tags: python, coordinates

was already looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963054/finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096783/using-distance-matrix-to-find-coordinate-points-of-set-of-points?newreg=5174f4e923d342ecb0e520839e196206) but I'm still struggling.
I have an array of distances (rssi values) of around 200 points. almost each point has a distance value to another point. I do not know if the values are consistent.
I like to translate the distances to xy coordinates to see what elements are close to each other. Clustering (k-means etc) could be good approach too, but I like to visualize the data.
Some other infos: only XY plane (if solution in XYZ is possible, ok too), language: python
 
Example:
Input: Distance Array i,j = index/node Id for only 5 Nodes

| . |  |  | . | . |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 29 | 19 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 17 | 4. | 3 |
| 29 | 17 | 0 | 1. | 2 |
| 19 | 4 | 1. | 0 | 6 |
| 2 | 3. | 2 | 6. | 0 |

Output:
| Node | X | Y |
| ---- | --|-- |

Comment: You should provide an example of what your data looks like and what you want it to look like. That would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is known as [multidimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling)