# Line intersection transversal

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, line, intersection

I have several random line segments. I have to check if there is any intersection between any two line segments. Lines may be connected or not.  What would be a good algorithm for this problem?

Comment: lines or line segments? If they are lines, then you just need to check if they are parallel.

Comment: hey,line segments not just lines. thanks anyway

Comment: @assylias if they are parallel they can still be equal (and thereby intersect...)

Comment: If you're going to ask for code examples (which you're not likely to get, since the algorithms are more than a handful of LOC), at the very least mention the language you're programming in (or explicitly mention you don't care in which language).

Comment: I have found line segment code. eventually I can write my own. But I was looking, something, say, you have random 100 line segments. And each time i have to compare with two line. so permutation of 100 line segments 100P2 = 9,900 which is huge I think. I was looking for something best. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Matthias, assuming we're talking about Euclidean Geometry, it all depends: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5334/do-2-equal-lines-also-count-as-intersecting

Comment: @rokonoid, yes, the naive way to find all intersections is O(n^2), where `n` is the number of segments. However, Bentley-Ottmann will find all intersections in `O((n+k)*log(n))` where `k` is the total number of intersections (ie. the algorithm is *"input sensitive"*).

Comment: hey, -@BartKiers thanks, Bentley-Ottmann algorithm is fine.

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957359/minimal-rectangle-containing-all-intersections-of-lines/10977575#10977575.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about line segments here (otherwise, simply compare the slopes of the lines: if they have unequal slopes, they intersect).

To find out if a [single] intersection exists in a set of 2 or more line segments, you can use the Shamos-Hoey algorithm.

To find *all* intersections in a set of 2 or more line segments, you can use the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm.

Implementation of the two, and other "sweep-line" based algorithms, are abundantly [available on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=Line+segment+intersection+code).